# БЭМ против SASS mixins

Tags: html, css, sass, бэм

Возник такой вопрос: можно задать стили для блока с помощью общего класса по БЭМ, например:

```
<div class = 'parent'>
   <button class = 'button parent__button'> button </button>
</div>

.button {
   border: none;
   background: white;
 }
 .parent__button {
    position: relative;
 }
```

А можно с помощью миксина или шаблона в SASS

```
@mixin button($border, $background) {
   border: $border;
   background: $background;
}
.parent__button {
   @include button(none, white);
}
```

Тогда HTML примет следующий вид, без общего универсального класса button:

```
<div class = 'parent'>
   <button class = 'parent__button'> button </button>
</div>
```

Таким образом можно заменять модификаторы БЭМ миксинами SASS или шаблонами SASS. Это снимает нагрузку с HTML и перенаправляет ее на СSS.

Как правильно верстать учитывая эти два подхода ?
Особенно интересует ответ человека который имел\имеет опыт в продакшине, какая практика используется в коммерческой разработке в контексте данного вопроса?. Применять БЭМ для общих стилей блока или элемента блока или пользоваться миксинами ? Благодарю за участие в этой битве).

Comment: Yaroslav Bondar, постарайтесь всегда сразу излагать суть. Потому что история вашего становления или начало происхождения вселенной - совсем не то, о чём тематика этого ресурса)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы снять нагрузку с HTML лучше используйте PUG. Вы немного путаетесь, два ваших кода что вы привели являются разными, они не заменяют друг друга.
В первом случае ваша кнопка является миксом. Она одновременно является БЭМ блоком button и элементом БЭМ блока parent. Это хороший вариант, потому что потом вы сможете использовать button где угодно в вашем проекте. Во втором случае кнопка уже не является самостоятельным блоком. Первый случай (микс) используется для того, чтобы задать элементу внешнюю геометрию.
Миксины никак не влияют на архитектуру проекта, они лишь позволяют вам избрежать дублирование кода в вашем проекте.

Comment: Чем `PUG` снимает нагрузку с `HTML` ?